# "or" vs "otherwise": difference

Tags: grammar

Do the words **"otherwise"** and **"or"** mean the same in the following context?

Are they both correct?

Here is the examples:

- John, you should follow the instructions that teacher said, ***or/otherwise*** you will not be able to complete the project.

Comment: both will do, **or else** is also possible

Answer (score 1):

> John, you should follow the instructions that teacher said, **otherwise** you will not be able to complete the project.

Use *otherwise*, because the second phrase makes a conclusion or resulting action, rather than a choice or alternative for which *or* would be better.

[*otherwise*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/otherwise):

> 1. *adverb*
>      You use otherwise after stating a situation or fact, in order to say what the result or consequence would be if this situation or fact was not the case.

However, *or* is commonly used in this kind of phrase in everyday speech, so you can't really say it is wrong.